# How to recognize mechanize sessions by Firefox?

Tags: python-2.7, firefox, mechanize, browser-automation

I'm using `mechanize` to login to a web page. I can login successfully and everything works. The thing is, when I open `Firefox` and I navigate the same web page, it asks for a login again. Although, I send the exact user agent info.

In other words, if I login to my gmail account from one Firefox window for example, I can go to my email from a new window/tab without re-login.

**How can I do the same thing with mechanize?**

Here is the code I'm using:

```
import mechanize
import cookielib

loginURL = 'http://esnidd053.emea.nsn-net.net/NIDD/home/Login'
browser = mechanize.Browser()

# Cookie Jar
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
browser.set_cookiejar(cj)

# Browser Options
browser.set_handle_robots(False)
browser.set_handle_equiv(True)
browser.set_handle_gzip(True)
browser.set_handle_redirect(True)
browser.set_handle_referer(True)

# Here I try to imitate firefox
browser.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64;   en-US; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Debian 3.2.73-2+deb7u1 Firefox/43.0')]
browser.open(loginURL)
browser.select_form(nr = 0)
browser.form['username'] = '<username>'
browser.form['password'] = '<password>'
login = browser.submit()
print login.read()
```

Comment: This is not an easy task, the reasons are: Firefox use its own way to save cookies to cookies.sqlite file in your Profile folder; but mechanize does not save session cookie by default. The only way, I see, is to instruct mechanize to save cookie to the db file cookies.sqlite, but you need to learn that whether firefox has their cookies encrypted.